# Dots change on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/8cj7C/

HTML:

```
<div id="scroll">
<div id="1" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="2" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="3" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="4" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

What I need to do is when I scroll for example to the second div using the scrollbar (not the scroll dots), the second dot will change to class `scroll_item_active`. I need help to do this!

I've been trying to do something with scrollTop and set 800, 1600, etc, but it's not working. Any good idea?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4aac15/smooth-scrolling-effect-in-javascript-using-jquery/

Check this article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/8cj7C/7/)**

Try this I have added something extra to your fiddle , click and try

### code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#first").addClass('scroll_item_active');
    var main = main = $('#scroll');
    $('.scroll_item').click(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var trgt = $(this).attr('id') + "1";
        target_offset = $('#' + trgt).offset(),
        target_top = target_offset.top;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target_top
        }, 500);
        main.children().removeClass('scroll_item_active');

        $(this).addClass('scroll_item_active');

    });

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        if ($("#first1").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
            $("#first").addClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#second").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#third").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#fourth").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
        }
        if ($("#second1").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
            $("#second").addClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#first").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#third").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#fourth").removeClass('scroll_item_active');

        }
        if ($("#third1").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
            $("#third").addClass('scroll_item_active');
           $("#first").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#second").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#fourth").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
        }
         if ($("#fourth1").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
            $("#fourth").addClass('scroll_item_active');
           $("#first").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#second").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
            $("#third").removeClass('scroll_item_active');
        }
    });
});
```

### html

```
<div id="scroll">
    <div id="first" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="second" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="third" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="fourth" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div id="first1"></div>
<div id="second1"></div>
<div id="third1"></div>
<div id="fourth1"></div>
```

### css

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#scroll {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 999;
}
.scroll_item {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.scroll_item:hover{
    background: #FFF;
}
.scroll_item_active {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#first1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0px;
}
#second1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
}
#third1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1600px;
}
#fourth1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2400px;
}
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to change the classes if you see at least 100 pixels of the div?

Comment: I've managed to do this by adding -100 in every `if` statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're looking for something more like this :

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">
    <div data-page="first"  class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div data-page="second" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div data-page="third"  class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
    <div data-page="fourth" class="scroll_item">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.scroll_item').on('click', function() {
    var elem   = $('#' + $(this).data('page')),
        scroll = elem.offset().top;

    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop : scroll}, 1000);

    $(this).addClass('scroll_item_active')
           .siblings('.scroll_item_active')
           .removeClass('scroll_item_active');
});

$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var elems    = $('#first, #second, #third, #fourth'),
        scrolled = $(this).scrollTop(),
        dataPage = elems.filter(function() {
            return $(this).offset().top + ($(this).height() / 2) >= scrolled;
        }).first();

    $('.scroll_item[data-page="'+dataPage.prop('id')+'"]')
              .addClass('scroll_item_active')
              .siblings('.scroll_item_active')
              .removeClass('scroll_item_active');
}).trigger('scroll');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8cj7C/3/)

Comment: Thank you, used in my code with minor correction: adding/removing 'scroll_item_active' class is not required within click event handler as it will be done by scroll event handler anyway.